# Controlling the size of the HTML file when saving file

Tags: jupyter-notebook, plotly

can someone help me to resize an HTML file produce with plotly in Jupyter?
 This is the code I am using to save to an HTML file:

```
    fig.write_html("D:\jupyter\image.html")
```

It works but now I want to control for the size. Here (https://plotly.com/python/interactive-html-export/) is suggested how to do it but I cannot get my head around to how specifically write the code to not get a big image

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you type `fig.write_html?` inside a cell you can read all the documentation, which is a little more explicit than the document you posted. In short

```py
fig.write_html("output.html",
               include_plotlyjs="cdn")
```

Should produce a file ~3MB smaller than the one you are getting now as this option point to the `plotly.js` online instead of include it on the output.

Comment: This ~3 MB is added for every figure. I used 3 figures so I got more than 9 MB reduction after using include_plotlyjs="cdn" . And you can use this with `fig.to_html(include_plotlyjs="cdn")` also.